# How to add a plugin as a jar to a grails project

Tags: maven, grails, plugins, dependencies

I created a custom plugin 'myPlugin' for GRAILS. I compiled and installed it as a binary (my-plugin-0.1.jar) file.

The jar file can't be found by grails in a "normal" project, because it only looks for my-plugin-0.1.zip (the plugin is defined within the plugins-block in BuildConfig.groovy)

How can i add the .jar file as a plugin?

Comment: then go to grails installation>ivy Cache >your_plugin_name> jars > yourjar.jar

Comment: Why jar? -> grails package-plugin --binary produces a jar. The plugin was already installed in ivyCache. It still cant be found. Perhaps i'll create a .zip file

Comment: If you don't deploy your plugin to a repository, you may be better off attaching it to your app as an inline plugin. That way, you don't need to package it and may do parallel development with your app.

Answer (score 4):

Binary plugins packaged as `jar` has to be referred in the `dependencies` section instead of the `plugins` section in `BuildConfig`

```
dependencies {
    compile "mygroup:myplugin:0.1"
}
```

or you can put the jar in application's `lib` directory which I would discourage. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add it in the dependencies block (not plugins) in BuildConfig.groovy.

Publish plugin installs the jar into local maven cache (/.m2). Verify the existence of the jar in .m2.

Also verify if the application using the plugin has mavenLocal enabled in repositories' buildConfig.